# Displaying adjacency list array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, adjacency-list

I have the following array that needs to be displayed as navigation

```
[items] => Array
        (
            [Electronics] => Array
                (
                    [level2] => Array
                        (
                            [Home Use] => Array
                                (
                                    [level3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Laptops] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => HP A very simple laptop
                                                            [1] => HP Tablet 
                                                            [2] => Acer Laptop 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [Desktops] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Acer Tablet 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [Tablets] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =>  
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [Business] => Array
                                (
                                    [level3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Tablets] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => HP A very simple laptop
                                                            [1] => HP Tablet 
                                                            [2] => Touchmate 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [Laptops] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Compaq 
                                                            [1] => IBM 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [Desktop] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Lenovo 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [Hotels] => Array
                (
                    [level2] => Array
                        (
                            [5 Stars] => Array
                                (
                                    [level3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Daily Basis] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Hilton 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [Montly Basis] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Hilton 
                                                            [1] => Intercon 
                                                            [2] => Marina Hotel 
                                                            [3] => Galaxy Plaza Hotel 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [4 Stars] => Array
                                (
                                    [level3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Daily Basis] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Address 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [Montly Basis] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Armada Al Barsha Hotel 
                                                            [1] => Everest International Hotel 
                                                            [2] => New Hotel 
                                                            [3] => Good Hotel 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [3 Stars] => Array
                                (
                                    [level3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Daily Basis] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Royal Garden Hotel 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [Montly Basis] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Galaxy Plaza Hotel 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [Entertainment] => Array
                (
                    [level2] => Array
                        (
                            [] => Array
                                (
                                    [level3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =>  
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [Services] => Array
                (
                    [level2] => Array
                        (
                            [] => Array
                                (
                                    [level3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [level4] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =>  
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

NOW...  i want to display this in Unordered list. I have the following function.

```
public function display($sorted_array)
{   


    $markup = '';

    foreach ($sorted_array as $key => $value) 
    {   

        if($key === 'Electronics' || $key ==='Hotels' || $key === 'Services' || $key === 'Entertainment')
        {
            $markup .= '<h1><li>';
        }

        $markup .= (is_array($value)) ? '<b>'.$key.'</b></li></ul></h1>'.$this->display($value) : '<ul><li>'.$value. '</li></ul>';

    }

    return '<ul>'.$markup . '</ul>';

}

Electronics

Home Use

Laptops

    HP A very simple laptop
    HP Tablet 
    Acer Laptop
```

Desktops

```
    Acer Tablet
```

Tablets

Business

```
Tablets

    HP A very simple laptop
    HP Tablet 
    Touchmate
```

Laptops

```
    Compaq 
    IBM
```

Desktop

```
    Lenovo
```

Hotels

```
5 Stars

Daily Basis

    Hilton
```

All the categories and subcategories are being displayed in the right order. However, i need to know where i should add an id so that i can add styles to sub categories and place them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you use id then you would use an id multiple times, so use class instead of id. One way is to keep a counter which represents the level. According that your function works properly, you would get something like this:

```
public function strip($string)
{
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
    $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
    $string = strtolower($string); //To lower case  
    return $string;
}

public function display($sorted_array, $level=0)
{   
    $level++;

    $markup = '';

    foreach ($sorted_array as $key => $value) 
    {   

        if($key === 'Electronics' || $key ==='Hotels' || $key === 'Services' || $key === 'Entertainment')
        {
            $markup .= '<h1><li id="'.$this->strip($key).'" class="level-'.$level.'">';
        }

        $markup .= (is_array($value)) ? '<b>'.$key.'</b></li></ul></h1>'.$this->display($value,$level) : '<ul><li id="'.$this->strip($key).'" class="level-'.$level.'">'.$value. '</li></ul>';

    }

    return '<ul>'.$markup . '</ul>';
}
```

Now you can use the level classes in your css.

```
.level-1 {

}
.level-2 {

}
...
```

Comment: I tried that, but it is assigning level1 to all the leaf nodes (last nodes with no child). 

This is a recursive function. If the current key is an array, the name of the key is printed and array is passed to the same function again so that when the current key is a value, it is printed.The problem is that in one iteration, the value to be printed can be anything; parent, child, sub-child, sub-sub-child, or a lead node. How to know the levels now?

Comment: So, in one iteration, either a KEY or a VALUE is printed.

The array is organized and is printed perfectly in correct order. All i want is to set appropriate ids so i could style them as standard navigation of categories and sub categories.

Comment: That level thing should work. Because your function is iterative it will increase when you call the function the second time. I edited my question. Now each `li` item will have an id.